# Mulberry trees can have both lobed and unlobed leaves?

Tags: leaves, mulberry

Guidebooks I have show mulberries as having both the characteristic roundly serrated, multi-lobed leaves, but also unlobed leaves.

Does this mean mulberries can have both lobed and unlobed leaves on the same tree, or are there different conditions under which the leaves are lobed/unlobed?

Comment: I've read that they don't have a consistent leaf shape. I'm not sure how true this is, offhand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White mulberry (*Morus alba*) could have both lobed and unlobed leaves in the same tree. I find more frequently unlobed leaves, but some plants (especially on young stages) can have mostly lobed leaves.

And on my books, *Morus alba* is describes as usual unlobed tree.

Answer (score 4):

Red Mulberry (Morus rubra) can also have lobed and unlobed leaves on the same tree. Young trees tend to have more lobed leaves, and mature trees tend to have fewer.